# Toolkit for parsing SOAP message

Tags: java, soap

As part of my project, I need to be able to parse a SOAP response from a remote service end-point, and convert it into a custom XML format. My project should be agnostic of the schema used by the SOAP response. However, my first step involves parsing the SOAP message and extracting the relevant sections - Headers, Body, Attachments, Faults. Currently, to do this I'm using the StaX parser.

I was wondering if there's any toolkit available to perform this task so that I wouldn't have to re-invent the wheel again. Especially more so when it comes to handling complexities related to retrieving binary data attachments w/ their correct Mime types, etc.

Some pseudo-code examples -

```
SOAPLib s = new SOAPLib(soapResp);
SOAPHeader h s.getHeader();
h.getHeaders();
String body = s.getBody()
SOAPAttachment sa = s.getAttachment(id);
...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The "SOAP with Attachments API for Java (SAAJ)" is built into the jdk in the [javax.xml.soap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/package-summary.html) package. A tutorial can be found [here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbhr.html).

The Api is based on the DOM, to parse a soap message you can either use the [SoapFactory#createElement(Element domElement)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPFactory.html#createElement%28org.w3c.dom.Element%29) method in `SOAPFactory` or the [MessageFactory#createMessage(MimeHeaders headers, InputStream in)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/MessageFactory.html#createMessage%28javax.xml.soap.MimeHeaders,%20java.io.InputStream%29) in `MessageFactory`.

Comment: I believe the SAAJ toolkit is provided to 'build' a SOAP message and not for parsing a SOAP message.